# after + doing vs I did, which one is correct or better?

Tags: past-tense

> It was my first time to do something after +
>
> - graduating from university
> - I graduated from university

Which one is better?

Comment: Which one do you think is better? Why? Please answer by editing your question, not as a comment.

Comment: @virolino I have no idea

Comment: Where did you get these examples from? Real life? An exercise book?

Comment: Real life, something I want to express.

Comment: From your understanding, what would be the difference between the two? Maybe small difference, maybe big difference.

Comment: I don't know, that's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sentence

> It was my first time to do something after I graduated from university.

it is very clear that you already graduated.

---

In the sentence

> It was my first time to do something after graduating from university.

the status of graduating is not specified in the verb (graduating). However, thanks to the context, we can understand that you already graduated, that it is not a hypothetical situation.

---

Compare with:

> Graduating from university was my biggest dream.

In this case, it is not sure what happened:

- I graduated
- I stopped having dreams
- both